# Supabase edge functions deno - Cannot find module in next js

Tags: supabase, edge-function

I'm using Next 13.4 and typescript.
I have a supabase edge function where I import from 2 different modules:

```
import { serve } from "https://deno.land/std@0.168.0/http/server.ts"
import { createClient } from 'https://esm.sh/@supabase/supabase-js@2?target=deno&no-check';
```

The function works well, but these import don't allow me to build my app and deploy it giving these errors which are technically the same:

```
Cannot find module 'https://deno.land/std@0.168.0/http/server.ts' or its corresponding type declarations.
Cannot find module 'https://esm.sh/@supabase/supabase-js@2?target=deno&no-check' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

I've seen the same issue here: https://github.com/supabase/supabase-js/issues/744

But no answer to it.

Comment: You need to figure out why your next app is trying to build files that are inside of `supabase/functions` when they aren't a part of your next application.

Comment: @AndrewSmith I don't think it's the case of building files, it's just when I run "next build" the linting step fails because of that issue. My supabase folder is outside of src folder.

Comment: The issue you linked to the user is sharing files between `supabase/functions` and his application, this would lead to your bundler or linter following the trail to where these files are and all their dependencies. Your bundler won't understand deno as its running in node, so you need to not share files between the `supabase/functions` and your application itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can add supabase to the exclude section of `tsconfig.json`

```
"exclude": ["node_modules", "supabase"],
```